# How do I ensure that my fitness keep in range after mutation steps?

Tags: java, benchmarking, evolutionary-algorithm, mutation

I use sphere benchmark function to test evolutionary strategy code with uncorrelate one step size mutation as follow:

```
public class cromosome {
 private double[] variable = new double[2];
    private double[] stepSize = new double[2];
    private double fitness=0;
    }

//=========================method set fitness=========================================
    public void setFitness() {
        for (int i=0; i<variable.length; i++) {
            fitness += variable[i]*variable[i];  
        } 
        System.out.println("fitness=  " + fitness);
    }
```

my values are in range[-10;+10] after applying mutation steps its seems that my fitness is out of range.
this my mutation method

```
 public static cromosome Mutation(cromosome cro) {
        //Mutations with no correlation with one step size
        Random r = new Random();
        double a = r.nextGaussian();
        double lr = 1 / (Math.sqrt(cro.getVariableLenght()));
        double[] newMutationStep = new double[1];
        newMutationStep[0] = cro.getMutationStep(0) * (Math.exp(lr * a));

        double[] newVariable = new double[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < cro.getVariableLenght(); i++) {
            double b = r.nextGaussian();
            newVariable[i] = cro.getVariable(i) + newMutationStep[0] * b;
        }
        cromosome newKromosom = new cromosome(newVariable[0], newVariable[1], newMutationStep[0]);
        return newKromosom;
    }
```

after many iteration the fitness values are out of range, how can I control my fitness ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using r.nextGaussian(). The spread on this variable is larger than 1. Meaning you will sometimes get values below -1 or above 1. This is probably the source of the issue.
To fix it add a validation such as:

```
double a = r.nextGaussian();
if(a < -1){a = -1;}else if(a > 1){a = 1;}
```

After this handle it in the same way you are doing now.